# Bidirectional Syncing with Android using Unison and MTP

Tags: mount, android, sync, mtp, unison

I'm currently trying to sync bidirectionally some folders of my PC (Ubuntu 18.04) with my Smartphone (Fairphone 3, Android 9) via MTP using Unison. I thought that this should be pretty easy, but it turned out to be rather complicated. Unison is able to detect if two versions of a file exist in the two sync directories. However, than two problems occur:

1. Unison cannot detect which one of the files is the up-to-date version. I can set this manually, but this is rather time consuming and also prone to errors, in case I make a mistake.
2. Unison cannot overwrite the old version of the file with the up-to-date version.

I here document what I have done so far:

1. Create a mount directory for the file system of the smartphone:

```
mkdir /tmp/fp3
```

2. Mount the filesystem of the phone:

```
jmtpfs -o allow_other /tmp/fp3
```

3. Sync the directory of the phone with the according directory of the PC. Both directories contain different versions of the file "test":

```
unison -fat ~/Desktop/Test /tmp/fp3/SD-Card/Home/Test
```

The last command returns the following output in the console. Unison cannot detect the appropriate syncing direction for the file "test" and I'm setting it manually with ">":

```
Contacting server...
Looking for changes
Reconciling changes

Desktop/Test   Home/Test          
new file ====> new file   test  [] >

Proceed with propagating updates? [] y
Propagating updates


UNISON 2.48.4 started propagating changes at 10:29:48.42 on 06 Mar 2020
[BGN] Updating file test from /home/$USER/Desktop/Test to /tmp/fp3/SD-Card/Home/Test
Failed: Error in renaming /tmp/fp3/SD-Card/Home/Test/.unison.test.92833400e4472a77b19cca039512131e.unison.tmp to /tmp/fp3/SD-Card/Home/Test/test:
Input/output error [rename(/tmp/fp3/SD-Card/Home/Test/.unison.test.92833400e4472a77b19cca039512131e.unison.tmp)]
100%  00:00 ETAFailed [test]: Error in renaming /tmp/fp3/SD-Card/Home/Test/.unison.test.92833400e4472a77b19cca039512131e.unison.tmp to /tmp/fp3/SD-Card/Home/Test/test:
Input/output error [rename(/tmp/fp3/SD-Card/Home/Test/.unison.test.92833400e4472a77b19cca039512131e.unison.tmp)]
UNISON 2.48.4 finished propagating changes at 10:29:48.99 on 06 Mar 2020


Saving synchronizer state
Synchronization incomplete at 10:29:48  (0 items transferred, 0 skipped, 1 failed)
  failed: test
```

Looks like Unison is first copying an up-to-date version of the file "test" with the name ".unison.test.92833400e4472a77b19cca039512131e.uni son.tmp" into the directory where the old version of "test" sits. Then it is trying to rename the up-to-date version, which seems to fail.
Any ideas what could cause this error? Any help is highly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: I would guess this is some *permissions* problem. It looks like Unison can *copy* stuff to your phone's mounted filesystem just fine, but it can't *edit* existing files, which is what renaming that `tmp` file to the test file would be doing. Maybe you just have to mount the phone's filesystem ... differently? (sorry that I don't know enough to be more precise here)

Comment: Also, welcome to the StackExchange network! :) Your question here isn't really *about* Ubuntu, so if you don't figure out an answer to your question here within a couple days, you could try posting this on another SE site. Maybe on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I also thought this might be a permission problem and therefore tried to mount the filesystem with the following fuse options: "jmtpfs -o allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000 /tmp/fp3" However, this didn't solve my problem, I still get the same error.

Comment: I am seeing a similar "Error in renaming" problem on my jmtpfs mount from my phone, using unison.   When it is finished there is a .unision file left.
1/ mv the .unison file over the final destination will fail   2/ Delete the destination file and the mv will succeed.  3/  cp the .unison on top of the destainion then delete the .unison also works.   Just direct 'mv' (rename) fails.    No options found in unison to resolve the problem.   File names are correct in case, so it isn't a case insensitivity problem.